# Accomplish screen sharing using WebRTC

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, screensharing

I need to implement screen sharing using WebRTC. I know that WebRTC supports sharing of tab content but I need to share the whole screen.
A solution I am thinking of is to frequently take screenshots and using WebRTC data channel transfer the image to other party. The other party will then update the image each time a new image is received.

Is this possible to accomplish? Particularly I am wondering if it is possible to transfer image using WebRTC data channel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could transfer an image via the DataChannel but the bigger problem will be to capture the screen from inside of the JavaScript sandbox. I suspect that's just not possible without some kind of browser extension.

Answer (score 9):

getUserMedia supports screensharing of the whole screen, not just the tab content.

I've done a screen capture demo (using the mandatory constraint chromeMediaSource: 'screen') which pipes the stream into an RTCPeerConnection: https://simpl.info/screencapture.

The chrome.tabCapture API gets tab content, but of course that's not what you want: example [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/Screensharing-with-WebRTC) (though the code is now broken).

EDIT: added HTTPS to links: this is required for screencapture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. getUserMedia is really what I need. But in order to test it locally seems I'll have to install some HTTPS server right?

Comment: Is it possible to get 60FPS with this method? I tried but seems far from ideal.

Comment: Is there a way to get screen sharing now as chrome doesn't have the flag that enables screen sharing in the latest version.

Comment: Screen capture is now available for Chrome on Android behind a flag. See the demo at https://simpl.info/sc, and Paul Kinlan's article at https://paul.kinlan.me/screen-recording-with-getUserMedia-and-WebRTC/.

Answer (score 7):

Screensharing is available via an experimental `getUserMedia` constraint in Chrome ([not yet available in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351442/firefox-22-mozgetusermedia-using-screen-as-device-source/)).

You'll need to first enable the flag called `Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia()` in `chrome://flags`.

There's a nice example of how to capture the screen here: https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html.

Comment: Thanks, good example. But when I copy the html content to my local html file it doesn't work. Seems I'll need to install HTTPS server.

Comment: Not anymore, it seems: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/TPQVKZnsF5g

Comment: `Enable screen capture support` flag is removed from Chrome

Comment: Is there a newer way introduced for Screen capturing ?

Comment: Anyone know if there's a replacement flag or how to enable screen capture via getUserMedia() ?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this Chrome Extension, it has implemented desktop sharing and it's pretty good. 
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/