# Where is a comprehensive list of supported media types when recording with the Media * API?

Tags: javascript, web, web-audio-api, mediastream, mediarecorder-api

I am trying to learn how to record media in the browser and I may be over-complicating things. There is an abundant supply of straight-forward examples but I got bogged down at the part when the recordings are pushed to a `Blob` object with an arbitrarily selected media type without checking whether that format is supported. Therefore I assume there is a list or people just keep building on past experiences.

For example,
from [Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample/blob/master/script.js):

```
      mediaOptions = {
        video: {
          tag: 'video',
          type: 'video/webm',
          ext: '.mp4',
          gUM: {video: true, audio: true}
        },
        audio: {
          tag: 'audio',
          type: 'audio/ogg',
          ext: '.ogg',
          gUM: {audio: true}
        }
      };
  media = mv.checked ? mediaOptions.video : mediaOptions.audio;
//...
function makeLink(){
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
//...
```

or from [MDN's Using the Media Stream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API):

```
 var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
```

The [specs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob) and [their](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) [various](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) are mostly generic descriptions which is completely understandable as user agents need to implement them.

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466078/specifying-codecs-with-mediarecorder) is pretty much what I had in mind but I was wondering whether there is an easier accessible and up-to-date list somewhere?

---

UPDATE:
I pretty much feel like as if I just crawled out from under a rock because as soon as I posted this I realized the 2 most obvious ways...

1. Query the media format on http://caniuse.com/
2. [MDN's Supported Media Formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

After @Kaiido's pointers:

3. [Media Recorder API's `isTypeSupported`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html#example1)
4. [`getSupportedTypes()`](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/pull/65)

Comment: There is currently no way in the API to get the list of all supported mime-types, but you can call `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(mime)`. Also, you can let the browser defaults everywhere (`new Blob(chunks)`), which currently encodes as VP8 / opus on both chrome and FF.

Comment: Ps : there is this [`getSupportedTypes()` pull request](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/pull/65) which has been made to specs, so let's hope it will land in browsers any time soon.

Comment: Just a note that the list returned by `getSupportedTypes()` method doesn't guarantee (unfortunately) that the selected mime-type is really supported. You can create a video blob with mime-type `video/x-matroska;codecs=vp9` (Chrome Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (x86_64) on MacOS claims it is supported), paste it to the <video> HTML element, but you won't be able to play that video.

Comment: See live test https://www.sitelint.com/lab/media-recoder-supported-mime-type/ to check for supported codecs, btw